# How do I avoid round-tripping large quantities of data in Relay Mutations?

Tags: relayjs

Suppose I have a React Component that controls a `textarea` that contains the contents of a blog post. As the user changes the blog post, I update the Relay Store with a `Mutation`:

```
Relay.createContainer(
  React.createClass({
    handleChange(event) {
      Relay.Store.update(new BlogBodyMutation({
        body: event.target.value,
        blog: this.props.blog
      }))
    },
    render() {
      return (
        <textarea
          value={ this.props.blog.body }
          onChange={ this.handleChange }
        />
      );
    }
  }), {
    fragments: {
      blog: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Blog {
          body
          ${ BlogBodyMutation.getFragment('blog') }
        }
      `
    }
  }
)

class BlogBodyMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  static fragments = {
    blog: () => Relay.QL`fragment on Blog { id }`
  };
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation { blog }`
  }
  getVariables() {
    return {
      id: this.props.blog.id,
      body: this.props.body
    }
  }
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`fragment on BlogMutationPayload { blog { body } }`
  }
  getConfigs() {
    return [{ type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE', fieldIDs: { blog: this.props.blog.id }}]
  }
}
```

**The problem**: Every time I update the Store with a Mutation, Relay round-trips the entire blog post to and from the backend! Suppose that the post is 50KB, even with a debounce that's 50KB + some bytes there and back for every debounced edit. Is there any way to avoid this?

I've experimented a bit, but haven't found a solution that works. I've tried using optimistic responses with an empty payload and no field configs, but that seems weird and doesn't actually work well given a controlled `textarea`.

Answer (score 3):

You're basically asking for a way to permanently "write" an optimistic update to the store - that's not supported by Relay. The only way to truly affect the Relay store is to use actual GraphQL mutations & queries.

That's not the end of the world, though. In your case, you basically just want the client to make it's own changes, independent of what the server does.

I'd recommend you manage the "blog body" state outside of Relay. You can store it anywhere you like - component state, a Redux store, etc. You can initialize the blog body state via a Relay query (that's no different), but afterwards just manage it yourself.

To record the blog body change on the server, switch back to using a Relay mutation, but don't declare any `FIELDS_CHANGE` configs or anything. That will instruct Relay not to try to refetch the blog body data and save you the roundtrip you are trying to avoid.

Keep in mind, though, that with this solution you're making a direct tradeoff between correctness (Relay attempts to ensure this) and performance. A classic tradeoff, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `applyUpdate` method instead of the standard `update`. https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/docs/APIReference-Store.md#applyupdate-static-method

This function creates a transaction without committing it to your backend. You could use that to debouce your `handleChange` method. However you will have to keep track of your older mutations and commit them when you want to.

Comment: Thanks XuoriG. I've played with `applyUpdate` already, for debouncing actually. Really nice addition. Still, for the transaction that you eventually do decide to commit—that data will need to make a round trip. Right? Is there some way to use this new API to send the data and not expect the data back in the response body? I'm thinking something like from the pre-Relay world where you would PUT some data and get a 200.

Comment: I see what you mean now. As far as I know that's not possible although maybe someone knows a trick :)

Comment: Hey just noticed you did the PR for `applyUpdate()`. Thank you :D